# Can I start few frames and loop the rest of the frame without programmatically call setProgress()?

Tags: android, lottie, bodymovin

I want to make an animation e.g. showing something from very small in size to normal size and then repeat (loop) a set of frames.

Is that possible just by using AE + Bodymovin?

I know I can set the frame 0 to 100 and then loop between 101 to 300 frame but it would be nice if there was some kind of way to specify it inside the json file.

Answer (score 2):

```
ivIconVoice.playAnimation()
```

Set Frame Min and Max value.

```
ivIconVoice.setMinAndMaxFrame(65, 90)
```